# How would I improve my collision blocking system in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I nailed a collision *detection* system, but now i'm trying to make a system that makes it so that, when the function is called, the items in the parameters aren't able to touch each other. I'm fairly new to JavaScript and its the first language ive really tried to learn. The way my rectangles are being drawn is so that x and y are in the middle of the rect, rather than in the top left corner of it. The system i've built *technically* works, but only if its a perfect square, for some reason rectangles are buggy and that i cant figure out. Even when it is a perfect square though, it seems clunky and really bad compared to what i'm used to, which is code.org's item1.collide(item2); which works perfectly and exactly how I want, but i cant find the code behind that. I am using p5.js, by the way.

Here is how i'm drawing my rectangles:

```
rect(this.x-this.width/2,this.y-this.height/2,this.width,this.height);
```

And here is the blockCollision function I currently have:

```
function blockCollision(a,b){
    if(a.x+a.width/2 > b.x-b.width/2 &&
    a.x-a.width/2 < b.x+b.width/2 &&
    a.y-a.height/2 < b.y+b.height/2 &&
    a.y+a.height/2 > b.y-b.height/2) {
        if(a.x<b.x-b.width/2) a.x=b.x-b.width/2-a.width/2;
        if(a.x>b.x+b.width/2) a.x=b.x+b.width/2+a.width/2;
        if(a.y<b.x-b.height/2) a.y=b.x-b.height/2-a.height/2;
        if(a.y>b.x+b.height/2) a.y=b.x+b.height/2+a.height/2;
     }
}
```

Also, here is the entire code download if It helps: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-F5CHOIQvvGVlR3Njd1M1NLS1E

Answer (score 0):

I presume by "block collision", you mean that you would like to move one of the blocks in the "opposite" direction of the collision so that the collision does not happen.

What you need to do is essentially determine the direction of the collision (top/bottom/left/right), and move the offending block away:

```
function blockCollision(a, b) {
  // Assuming (0, 0) is the top left corner
  const aTop = a.y - a.height / 2;
  const aBottom = a.y + a.height / 2;
  const aLeft = a.x - a.width / 2;
  const aRight = a.x + a.width / 2;

  const bTop = b.y - b.height / 2;
  const bBottom = b.y + b.height / 2;
  const bLeft = b.x - b.width / 2;
  const bRight = b.x + b.width / 2;

  const collisions = [];

  if (aTop <= bTop && aBottom >= bTop) {
    // a is above B, potential collision

    if (aLeft <= bRight && bLeft <= aRight) {
      // Prevent collision, push a to the top
      a.y = bTop - (a.height / 2) - 1;
    }
  }

  if (aBottom >= bBottom && aTop <= bBottom) {
    // a is below B, potential collision

    if (aLeft <= bRight && bLeft <= aRight) {
      // Prevent collision
      a.y = bBottom + (a.height / 2) + 1;
    }
  }

  if (aLeft <= bLeft && aRight >= bLeft) {
    // a is left of B, potential collision

    if (aTop <= bBottom && bTop <= aBottom) {
      // Prevent collision, push a to the left
      a.x = bLeft - (a.width / 2) - 1;
    }
  }

  if (aRight >= bRight && aLeft <= bRight) {
    // a is right of B, potential collision

    if (aTop <= bBottom && bTop <= aBottom) { 
      // Prevent collision, push a to the right
      a.x = bRight + (a.width / 2) + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

See [codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWxLGB).